# very small table hanging on "sorting results"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 50 rows in it. It is a table linking a document id to the type of document it is. It has a primary key, no indexes, a field for the name, 1 integer field, several boolean fields. The query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM documentTypes WHERE deprecated != 1 order by name asc
```

has been on "Sorting Result" for a good 7 minutes now. (This is an old table, and has never done this before) Rather than the table itself, it seems like this indicates some problem with my server or some tangentially related table. **What situation can cause a very small table to hang on "Sorting Result"?**

It is a pivot table, but in this context the table is being queried on its own, to generate a list of documents.

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `documentTypes` (
  `id` INT(3) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(1200) NOT NULL,
  `hidden` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `numAllowedPer` INT(2) NOT NULL,
  `pref1` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pref2` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deprecated` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And results of `EXPLAIN`

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id, name FROM documentTypes WHERE deprecated != 1 ORDER BY name asc

possible_keys: NULL
rows: 50
Extra: Using where; Using filesort
```

With or without an index on `deprecated` it should not take this long to run a query. Since there are only 50 rows, the difference should be negligible.

**UPDATE**

I am fairly certain it has nothing to do with the table itself. The question is really, what could be happening on the server that would cause this type of issue?

Comment: Yep, that's pretty suspect. It's InnoDB... have you just `mysqldump`'d the table and rebuilt it? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html

Comment: does it always hang so long?

Comment: @Aris not the table has been around for years with no issue

Comment: why do your queries not match, your explain is using a different table then your top query?

Comment: @cmorrissey whoops, I changed the name of the table so as not to publicize my table schema, and I forgot to change that one.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski nope, no dump or anything being done on it

Comment: I assume you see nothing else of concern in `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or you'd have reported it...  I wouldn't expect it to hang rather than fail outright,  but is the server's `/tmp` (or wherever MySQL is putting temp data) full or corrupt? Still, 50 rows shouldn't be writing there.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski processlist had many other things waiting behind it, they were all some flavor of "waiting for ... lock", that was the only one that was sorting

Answer (score 1):

Run the following queries,

```
REPAIR TABLE documentTypes
```

AND

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE documentTypes
```

Comment: REPAIR TABLE isn't supported by InnoDB, that's why I suggest dumping and reloading it.

Comment: sorry, i mean "check table" reported it was fine. I am sure the table itself is fine